# How does "get_user_pages" work (For linux driver)

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

Working on a Linux PCI driver,  now I'm trying to write codes for DMA using scatter/gather.

For now, I've learned that to access to DMA datas directly from User space, we need to pin user space pages to kernel space.

And to do this, we have `get_user_pages`, its full definition is like:

```
int get_user_pages(struct task_struct * tsk,  
    struct mm_struct * mm,  
    unsigned long start,  
    int nr_pages,  
    int write,  
    int force,  
    struct page ** pages,  
    struct vm_area_struct ** vmas);
```

My first question is about the `struct page ** pages`. Here do we need to allocate memory(using `kcalloc` for ex.) for the `pages` before calling the `get_user_pages`?

My second question is about the `unsigned long start`, on the man page, it says "starting user address", does it mean that, if I declare a pointer in user space like `int *p`, the "starting user address" I should pass to kernel space is `p`?

My third question is also about the `unsigned long start`, if I understand correctly in the second question, then how can we make sure that this address begins exactly at the beginning of a page?

So three questions, thanks for advance.

Comment: using `posix_memalign()` you are sure it's aligned or you check it after a `malloc()/mmap() MAP_ANONYMOUS`. If not, you can over-allocate and align yourself the pointer. (keep the original pointer to free the memory)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My first question is about the struct page ** pages. Here do we need to allocate memory(using kcalloc for ex.) for the pages before calling the get_user_pages?

You can, but it's not mandatory, an array is sufficent (its size depends on `nr_pages`)

If you want to pin 4 pages, `struct page *pages[4];` is enough.

> My second question is about the unsigned long start, on the man page, it says "starting user address", does it mean that, if I declare a pointer like int *p, the "starting user address" I should pass to kernel space is p?

This parameter should points to memory owned by your user process (like after a `malloc`).

> My third question is also about the unsigned long start, if I understand correctly in the second question, then how can we make sure that this address begins exactly at the beginning of a page?

I think you can do it with [`getpagesize`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getpagesize) function.

I think this blog entry: ["get_user_pages example"](http://krishnamohanlinux.blogspot.fr/2015/02/getuserpages-example.html) may help you.

Comment: That ["get_user_pages example"](http://krishnamohanlinux.blogspot.fr/2015/02/getuserpages-example.html) isn't great, though, as it assumes the user's buffer is page-aligned.