# confusing about what kmap does

Tags: c, linux, kernel

so I read that kmap is mapping physical page to the kernel memory but when I use this to edit some user pointer (like copy to user), but  when I edit the buffer that kmap return to me it doing nothing . isn't it should map the user memory to the kernel and return the virtual address that points the physical user memory ?
this is my code

```
asmlinkage long sys_call(char __user *buf)
{
  struct page *pages[1];

 get_user_pages(buf, 1, FOLL_WRITE, pages, NULL);
  kbuf=kmap(pages[0]);
 kbuf[0]='o';
 kbuf[1]='k';
 kumap(kbuf);

 }
```

the user code

```
int main()
{
 char t[10]="not ok";
 sys_call(t);
 printf("%d\n",t);
 
}
```

then the output is 'not ok' instead of 'ok ok'

Comment: `get_user_pages` works with **page-aligned** addresses, however I don't see in your code how you ensure that `buf` is properly aligned. See also [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36337942/how-does-get-user-pages-work-for-linux-driver).

Comment: @Tsyvarev but I only need the first physical  address don't I?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "I only need the first physical address". If page size is 4k, and `buf` points e.g. to address 5k, then it is impossible to map the memory **exactly** started at buf. Probably, `get_user_pages` will map area from [4k; 8k]. And when you write into the first byte of that area (`kbuf[0]='o';`), you write a byte at 4k, not at 5k which is value of `buf`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev so in order to solve it I need the right vm_area because virt_to_ph didnt worked as well

Comment: @Tsyvarev so how copy to user do that?

Comment: `copy_to_user` does not "pin" accessed pages via `get_user_pages` or such. Instead, `copy_to_user` is allowed to page fault and interacts with page fault handler.

Comment: @Tsyvarev one last question if I will map few page i may find where the address is?